# How to fix logger while migrating from spring-boot 1.2.2 to 2.3

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, slf4j, lombok

I am working on a task that involves migration of a spring-boot 1.2.2 based project to spring-boot 2.3.RELEASE.
After updating to spring-boot 2.3.RELEASE. I have encountered some compile-time errors. After fixing all the errors. now my project is compiling successfully but in the run time I am getting some errors.
I am new to spring-boot. please help me if you have any suggestion or solution.

 
**pom.xml**

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
           <relativePath/>
        </parent>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**This is not the actual pom I have removed some of the snippets to make it shorter** 
**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.encoderInit(OutputStreamAppender.java:180)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.setOutputStream(OutputStreamAppender.java:171)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:206)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService.getInstance(LogFactoryService.java:46)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService.getInstance(LogFactoryService.java:41)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
        at com.snapdeal.payments.consumercredit.ConsumerCreditApplication.main(ConsumerCreditApplication.java:44)
        ... 8 more
```

Here is a little bit of code on how I have used logger in my code.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Controller
public class AbstractController {

    protected void handleRequestError(BindingResult results) {
        log.error("xxxx");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing jars/modules from different versions never do that as that will lead to strange issues. You are mixing 2.3, 1.3 and 1.4 modules don't. You also added dependencies like `spring-tx` and `spring-context-support` which are already part of the different starters. So in short your dependencies are a bit messy fix those and use a compatible version of the `logstash-logback-encoder`, which is probably the main culprit pulling in an implementation depending on a older SLF4j API.

Answer (score 1):

In the pom you still have old versions of spring boot, so there seems to be a clash of versions:

For example, you write:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is still something that belongs to spring boot 1.X - so fix that first please and rerun.

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see the whole tree of dependencies and check that all the spring boot related stuff is of the same desired version

Comment: hey,
I have replaced these two dependencies with the latest spring-boot 2.X version.
spring-boot-starter-log4j -> spring-boot-starter-log4j2
spring-boot-starter-ws -> spring-boot-starter-web-services
and omit the version name. but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: So are you sure all the spring dependencies are of the same version? Open up the artifact jar with winrar or something, navigate to BOOT-INF/lib and check

Comment: I have just checked them and found all the version corresponding to spring is correct. To validate them I have their official website [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html)

Comment: Sorry, but something is still wrong with you versioning. The exception in the question basically says that logback is of incompatible version. So you have to track how did it appear in the final artifact with mvn dependency:free